# Sending Email using VSCode (spring-boot-starter-email)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am implementing  how to send email using spring boot
I am trying to implement this in visual studio code.
But it gives me the following error

[image]

I added the following two dependencies in my pom.xml for email configuration:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

my main bootstrap class:

```
   @SpringBootApplication
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
  "email"
  })

   public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    
    Mail mail = new Mail();
    
        mail.setMailFrom("abc@gmail.com");
        mail.setMailTo("xyz@gmail.com");
        mail.setMailSubject("Hi");
        mail.setMailContent("Hope you are doing well");
        
    
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, 
     args);
        MailService mailService = (MailService) ctx.getBean("mailService");
        
      mailService.sendEmail(mail);  

    
     }
```

I think my error is related to the `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"email"})` annotation that I have used above

Can anyone help me with the error?

Comment: Why do you think that you need @ComponentScan? It should work without ComponentScan, if all your Spring-Beans are below the package of your Application class. Do you have a class named "mailService"?

Comment: I ran my project after removing ComponentScan. It gives me a different error. Please see my updated question. and yes I have a class named mailservice @TomStroemer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we don't know the package structure it is difficult to tell what should be there in the basePackages inside `@ComponentScan`

Firstly, please move your Application class to one level up in the package structure, so that it reads all packages under it by default and remove the basePackages in component scan. So, it should be just `@ComponentScan`

That is, if all your classes are in package `com.test.mailer` then your Application class file should be in `com.test`

Try this and let us know, also I hope you have the `@Service` annotation as `@Service("mailService")`

**Update:**
Since the user has updated the question later, I am posting the solution that worked for him.

He moved the class one level up and removed the basePackages and it worked for him. As stated in the first part of my answer.

Alternatively, he could have changed `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"email"})` to `@ComponentScan("java.risknucleus")` in the same structure.

Comment: Please see my updated question.I posted my code structure and Yes I do have the Service annotation.  @Sudoss

Comment: So the first part of my answer should work for you. Please move the application class out of the `email` folder and remove the `basePackages` from component scan

Comment: Okay! Let me try and will let you know. @Sudoss

Comment: I moved my class out of email folder and removed basePackages and I am getting a ClassCastException which I have mentioned in my question. Can you please help me? To see code please follow this link https://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-boot-tutorials/how-to-send-email-using-spring-boot  @Sudoss

Comment: This is a separate error. Please ask a new question for this and accept this answer as it has resolved your query.